# Characteristic function on metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a Metric Space and $M \subseteq X$.

In what points is the Characteristic Function  $\chi_M(x): X \longrightarrow\mathbb R:=   
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } x \in M \\[.2cm]
0 & \text{if } x \notin M 
\end{cases} \quad$
continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. If $x$ belongs to the boundary of $M$ then, by definition of boundary, for all integer $n>0$, there is a point $y_n\in B(x,1/n)\cap M$ and 
there is a point $z_n\in B(x,1/n)\cap M^c$. Note that $f(y_n)=1$ and $f(z_n)=0$. Moreover $y_n\to x$, $z_n\to x$. What may we conclude?

What happens if $x$ is not in the boundary of $M$, that is if $x$ is in the interior of $M$ or if $x$ is in the interior of $M^c$?

Comment: This helped me alot thank you

Comment: You are welcome!!